# Rails: creating a scope or ordered query based on an association or alternatively a serialized attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wish to order my Story index with "viewed stories" (stories marked as viewed by the user) ascending, placing them last in the user's feed while "unviewed" stories appear first.

I have tracked whether a user has seen a Story with a model called View.
A scroll event on the client end sends an ajax request that creates a view with the story_id and the User_id:

```
class ViewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @view = @user.views.find_or_create_by!(story_id: @story.id)
    render json: {viewed: true, id: @story.id}
  end
end
```

The models are associated as such:

```
class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :story
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :stories, through: :favorites
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :viewed_by_users, Array
  has_many :views
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, through: :favorites
end
```

As you can see I'm already using a join Through table for favorites so a @user.stories or a @story.users reflects favorites rather than views.
If I want to examine whether a story has been viewed by a user, I can do something like so:

```
current_user.views.exists?(story: @story)
#Returns true or false when examining an instance of story.
```

I've also serialized an attrubute on story for convenience which is populated with user ids representing which users have viewed a story.
I may want to do away with the attribute later depending on what I can get to work. In the meantime I can examine it like so:

```
stories_not_viewed = Story.all.select { |s| s.viewed_by_users.include?(current_user) }
#returns an array of stories that have been viewed by current_user.
```

Now I am struggling to make either a scope in my model or a .order query in my controller which places a user's viewed stories at the tail end of the index (ascending).

I have a stories controller like this (with pagination):

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    page = params[:page].try(:to_i) || 1
    story_index = page - 1
    @stories = Story.includes(:users).limit(15).offset(story_index * 15)
    render json: @stories
  end
end
```

I have not been able to figure out how to write a default scope which accounts for my views association. It seems I would have to pass the current_user to the model, write some logic that finds whether the users id is in the View association for each story and if so, order those stories last (ascending). I've tried many different class methods here but for the life of me, I can not figure this out. Any examples of something similar to this would be appreciated.

the other alternative is if I change my design slightly, I can make the @stories index simply return unviewed stories and make a different endpoint for viewed stories, letting the user toggle the front-end view with a button that says "show viewed stories" or "show unviewed stories".

I have not been able to get this working either. I'd need it to work with my active record query rather than an array so I can keep my pagination.
I think I need some thing like this:

```
@stories = Story.where.not viewed_by_users.include?(current_user) #...etc
```

Obviously this is not correct query code and this is something I'm struggling with and trying to learn more about. It apparently needs to be something like:

```
where("viewed_by_users != ?", current_user)
```

...except current_user is one of many users in an array so that won't exactly work in this case.

I've been struggling with all of this for a while but haven't gotten anything to work. At this point I'd be happy to get either solution up and running.  I know this is a bit of a convulted one. Thanks for any help, tips, or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's a bare query on how this might work

```
select stories.*,
  IF (views.id is null, 0, 1) as viewed
from stories
left join views
  on(views.story_id = stories.id and views.user_id = 1)
where 1
group by stories.id
order by viewed, stories.id
```

So this basically selects all stories, do a join with views and limit views to user_id, and if the view record exists set as viewed, else set as not viewed, then order the records by giving the viewed ones a smaller index, and then order by story id ( you could change this to story.created_at for example )

Now to convert this to an active record query

```
Story.select('*', 'IF (views.id is null, 0, 1) as viewed')
  .join('left join views on(
       views.story_id = stories.id and views.user_id = ?
     )', user.id)
  .group(:id)
  .order(viewed: :asc)
  .order(id: :asc)
```

And to convert it into a scope or a method

```
def as_viewed_by(user)
  # same query here 
end
```

Here's an [sql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5930/9) you can check, 3 stories, and 3 users
user 1 has 1 view,
user 2 has 2 views,
and user 3 has 3 views,
change the `@user_id` and see the different ordering of the output

Try it and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and the fiddle example. I'm currently getting an error with this: PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "views"
LINE 1: SELECT *, IF (views.id is null, 0, 1) as viewed FROM "storie...   As I understand the error, I need to pass in each associated view somehow? I thought that's what the join was for. It's clear I need to really up my query game as I feel like I'm in an alternate rails universe.

Comment: This was an mysql query, apparently you are using postgres, so there will be some differences, like that if condition, probably other things too, I'm not that experienced in postgres, but I'll try to look things up

Comment: Thanks for any help. You've already done so much. I'm going to start reading up on postgres queries to see if I can figure out how to change the syntax. In the mean time I'll mark this as the the correct answer as I feel like the fiddle in and of itself demonstrates proof of concept. I just need to figure out how to leverage that to postgres.